# Get certificates from Windows-MY when there are some with the same alias

Tags: java, certificate, x509certificate

I am trying to retrieve all the certificates from windows-MY, but some of them have the same alias.

So, the following piece of code return just the first occurence with this alias:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");
Enumeration enumeration = keyStore.aliases();
while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
  String alias = enumeration.nextElement().toString();
  keyStore.getCertificateChain(alias);
  java.security.cert.Certificate[] chain = keyStore.getCertificateChain(alias);
  ...
}
```

Is there another way to retrieve the certificates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. The code mentioned in this Sun bug report works:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6672015

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried a for loop?

```
for (variable in object)
{
  code to be executed
}
```

Comment: The problem is I just know how to get the aliases from the keystore and to get the certificate I must use these alias. If the aliases are used more than once, then I just get the first certificate with this alias.  As you can see I'am already looping.